# Rails request failing for assets but asset is at location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

I'm using webpacker and I currently have a request failing for

https://.../packs/application-6b70966cde4a4aebc103.js

if I look in my public/packs folder I see.

```
deploy@platform:/var/www/.../current$ ll public/packs/
total 2427
drwxrwxr-x 2 deploy deploy     19 Jan 22 03:01 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 deploy deploy     18 Jan 22 03:01 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 893742 Jan 22 03:01 application-6b70966cde4a4aebc103.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy 222991 Jan 22 03:01 application-6b70966cde4a4aebc103.js.gz
```

And If I watch my logs I see in my http I have.

```
5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
192.168.1.xxx - - [22/Jan/2019:04:00:51 +0000] "GET /packs/application-6b70966cde4a4aebc103.js HTTP/1.0" 404 1564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

which also seen in my rails logs too.

```
F, [2019-01-22T04:09:44.951825 #20969] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/application-6b70966cde4a4aebc103.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  rollbar (2.15.5) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
  skylight (1.4.3) lib/skylight/probes/middleware.rb:33:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the static file server? It is explained [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline), you have to set `config.public_file_server.enabled` and `config.assets.compile` to `true` to have rails serving them.

Answer (score 0):

I was overlooking the fact it was failing at my http layer since my nginx config was incorrectly setup for my public folder. I for some reason thought rails was trying to handle the request but then noticed it was just because it was rendering the 404. Derp.